# Find End business date based on start date and number of days - excel

Tags: excel, vba

this is my first vba task. infact the first time i have used Alt+F11 opened the VB editor!
What i need to do is, calculate end date based on the start date and number of days.
I have the values for start date in column A and duration i.e.; number of days in column B.
Calculating business days is my second concern as of now. What I first need to know is, how can i use Worksheet_Change event?

What i thought of doing is, when user enters duration in any cell in column A say A(n), Cell B(n) gets selected in the Worksheet_Change event code.  And when Start Date is entered in B2, function to calculate End date is called. Please let me know if its a correct approach or not.

Also what caused trouble for me was, when I press Enter key after entering values in cells, the Worksheet event behaves abruptly.

Please help me solve this simple yet complex issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Kindly make sure you put this code in worksheet. Also this code applies to whole column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Column < 2 And Target.Count < 1 And Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Offset(0, 1) <> "" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 2) = DateAdd("d", CDbl(Target.Value), CDbl(Target.Offset(0, 1)))
    ElseIf Target.Offset(0, -1) <> "" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = DateAdd("d", CDbl(Target.Offset(0, -1)), CDbl(Target.Value))
    End If


    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You can directly call this function from excel sheet.the way you call any function like  =CalculateEndDate( arg,args) once you have defined the function in your vba code.

Comment: thanks! Could you also let me know if this is correct way to call the function to calculate end date say **CalculateEndDate(byVal startDate as date, byVal duration as integer) as Date** in vba: endDate =CalculateEndDate(strtDt,duration).                     Also, when I somehow got values for end date, it appeared as ########. So, how can I do formatting of date as dd-MMM-yyyy.

Comment: just double click on the top corner of column and you will see the value. Increase the column width.

Comment: Here is the link will be helpful for you to go step by step. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx

Comment: okies! thanks! hope after all this, i gt thru the solution asap!